# Typescript: Need help enforcing strict typing on function responses

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build a type for `actionHandlers` that enforces each key and value in the object to be a certain type and return the same object: `IPlatformState`.

```
export const actionHandlers: ActionHandler<PlatformActionTypes, IPlatformState> = {
  [PlatformActionTypes.SET_PRODUCT]: (state: IPlatformState, action: ISetProductAction) => {
    return {
    ...state, product: action.payload
  }},

  [PlatformActionTypes.SET_PRODUCT_GROUPS]: (state: IPlatformState, action: ISetProductGroupsAction) => ({
    ...state, productGroups: action.payload
  })
}
```

```
export type ActionFunction<T> = (state: T, payload: any) => T

export type ActionHandler<T extends PropertyKey, K> = {
  [key in T]: ActionFunction<T>
};
```

My issue is I can change any of the keys in the new object of the `ActionFunction` response to something not in `IPlatformState` and the TS compiler wont complain.

I basically need to create a type that ensures only an object that matches `IPlatformState` can be returned.

Answer (score 0):

The function declaration for `actionHandlers` should be able to enforce the types of the payload and return, you shouldn't need to define an alias.

As for the shape of the objects & the keys, can you just use interfaces to define everything? Here is some example code where Typescript Playground will enforce types [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=22&ssc=33&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUAWF0E8AOEA8iCgN4BQy1yA2gNYS4BcyAzmFKAOYC6rACgCUyALwA+ZADcA9sAAmFAL4UKAejXIAyjORwANvuQyYyMNjYoAtgFcOyAEYoTZgika41HLiG5jJsgoUoJCwiCgY2CQQAOoQAKqWyBAAHpAg8mxoWDhu0ciUNMjY+viCIhLScvIA3MqqMDYgCGDAMiDIuDI2UABiTQgCwJBWrJHEpHGJEEJjOdFTSYU0UBBgPR3DEFb16moyUMgA7sOYyNwQpFwIbA0Dre3G5tD9zQA86OJDrOizyOgFKgrNYbZDAXYIdr2VJwKz4fQoUQFYoQUrlfzISEgNgyBEAOn0Mm4AgA5CVCSSRCoKDJnn0Bm9xgsEpYvjC4QihEA)

```
interface ITheTypeOne {
    [key: string]: () => void
}

// So all of these must be of type key/string => void
interface ITheOneWeUse extends ITheTypeOne {
    help: () => void;
}

function yourFunc(item: ITheOneWeUse): ITheOneWeUse {
    return item
}

//or with generics

function otherFunc<T>(i: T): T {
    return i
}

const example = { help: () => console.log('hello') }

otherFunc<ITheOneWeUse>(example)
```